# Best Picks for Solo Carrying?

Tags: league-of-legends

What are the best champions to carry with? Lane doesn't matter, I'm currently Plat Elo. This is all assuming every game goes well and your ahead ( either by farm or early kills) and your team co-operates.

Comment: Theres to many variables to this question. A considered carry champ is only carriable on if you are ahead or good enough on him.

Also your question contradicts itself. The best carry champs or defiantly in the meta. If they weren't they wouldn't be carry champs.

Comment: Btw charkz ty for the Edits and such, i guess i can be considered a noob here

Comment: Try the God Tier champs suggested here. Those are strong in the current patch, fit into the meta and can usually tip the scales of a game: http://www.nerfplz.com/2016/02/2016-champion-tier-list-solo-queue_14.html

Comment: To be honest, if you're ahead *and* your team is cooperating, you don't really need to solo carry. You've probably already won.

Comment: It's cool, we all start somewhere. Just keep in mind to make the questions straight forward and easy to read/ understand. Avoid over information. We don't need to know everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Carry champs vary with a lot of variables but from your question I can give you tips for each lane. Also this is all vary opinion based due to so many variables.

All of these are as of this date 22/02/2016

TOP: Mundo,Trundle and Fiora are your carry champs, Gnar also if you are extremely good mechanically on him

Jungle:Elise,Graves,Xin,Udyr,Vi

Mid: Morgana,Lux,Yas,Zed,Talon,Diana,Ahri IMO any mid assassin should be able to carry until late game, but if it's late game you haven't really carried.

ADC: They're called Attack Damage Carry, so all should carry if fed. but top picks are: Ez,Lucian,Corki and Vayne.

Support: Best carry support imo is Blitz,Alistar,Thresh,Morg

Comment: Vi is considered a carry jungler? I'd say Lee Sin would be better

Comment: Lee isn't a carry jungler, cause he needs high mechanics to carry. Falls off terribly late game and is way harder to play then a point and click champion like Vi

Comment: True, but if you disregard the mechanics and assume you got ahead early, i would say lee is the better pick due to his higher damage output

Comment: Agreed, thanks for your view of things, i wouldn't have thought of Vi honestly

Comment: She won't win the game for you, but she can do so much damage fed, or just secure objectives easily. You're also in plat, that means Vi is a perfect carry as team mates aren't fully stupid.